# Change a Button Background Colour with JavaScript

Tags: function

I know it's a really basic thing but I can't change the button background colour using javascript. I want to change it using the class so i can do it for multiple classes. The javascript does link to the html.

The button code is:

`<button class ="buttonlink" onmouseover='hoverOver()'onclick="location.href='aboutme.html'">About Me</button><br>`

The function i tried is:

`function hoverOver(){
 var x = document.getElementsByClass('buttonlink');
 alert("x");
}`

I know this question has been asked before probably but I look and I couldn't find anything that directly linked, I am really new to this and don't really know what I am doing.

Comment: Are you just trying to change the color of a button on hover? Use CSS for this, not Javascript.

Comment: Yes, Okay thanks I will try with Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a buttons background color using a mouse hover is not done with Javascript(although it can be). The proper way to do it is with CSS using:

```
a.button:hover
```

If you want the background of a button to change when hovering over another part of the screen, then use javascript.

Here's a quick example:

```
 a.button a:hover{
    background: #FF0;
 }
```